# Separate column to different column and leave just one ID in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm new at coding and SQL. I have database like that:

```
ID| technique
--|----------
1 | 1
1 | 2
1 | 3
2 | 1
2 | 3
3 | 1
```

And I need this result

```
ID| technique1|technique2|technique3
--|-----------|----------|----------
1 | 1         | 2        | 3
2 | 1         |.         | 3
3 | 1         |.         |.
```

Is it possible?

Comment: As far I know. It is not possible. However, maybe someone knows.

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with conditional aggregation:

```
select id,
       max(case when technique = 1 then 1 end) as technique1,
       max(case when technique = 2 then 2 end) as technique2,
       max(case when technique = 3 then 3 end) as technique3
from t
group by id;
```

I am interpreting `.` as `NULL`.